# Video updates with significant latency in SDL

Tags: video, sdl, latency

If I remember correctly, I've met this problem before, but I can't remember how I solved it.
This is my program:

```
#include "SDL.h"

SDL_Surface *screen;
SDL_Event event;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    atexit(SDL_Quit);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);
    int x = 10,y = 10;
    while (1)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                exit(0);
        }
        int mx,my;
        Uint8 mstate = SDL_GetMouseState(&mx,&my);
        if (mstate & SDL_BUTTON(1)) x = mx,y = my;
        SDL_FillRect(screen,NULL,0);
        *(Uint32*)((Uint8*)screen->pixels+screen->pitch*y+x*sizeof(Uint32)) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        SDL_UpdateRect(screen,0,0,0,0);
    }
}
```

There's a white pixel in the black background and it moves to the position of mouse cursor when you press left mouse button. The problem is, it takes a significant fraction of second before the pixel appears in the new position. It's not a problem with just that pixel. When I try to move the program window, it doesn't respond immediately either. Nor does function printf if I put it somewhere in while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) loop. On the other hand, if I do the same with SDL_SetVideoMode, it responds at the moment when the event occurs.
Also, this only happens when FPS and resolution are high enough. If I set video mode to 320x200 rather than 640x480, or limit FPS, everything happens on time.
By the way, I use Ubuntu 11.10 with Mesa graphics drivers.
So is this problem a bug of SDL or some other software or is it my fault?

Comment: It works fine on my machine (windows7). Have you tried double buffering? You also don't need to do `SDL_FillRect()` every iteration, only when the mouse is clicked (and even then you could just change the single pixel).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my computer too (windows7), execution time inside the `while (1)` is under 1ms.

The fact that everything happens on time when you set video mode to a lower resolution leads to a lack of resources of your computer and/or unoptimized function on `Ubuntu 11.10 with Mesa graphics drivers`.

You need to profile the cpu time used for each function in order to find the bottleneck.

Some ideas :

- Place your drawing/Updating functions inside the `if (mstate & SDL_BUTTON(1))`
- Update the changed pixel -> `SDL_UpdateRect(screen,x,y,1,1);`
- Update the old white pixel to black instead of filling black all the screen.
- Add `SDL_Delay(10);` just before the end of your while(1) loop.